# Remove item from laravel cached array

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, caching

I'm trying to make a function that deletes the cache of a specific input field.
I made a JQuery function that executes an ajax call that executes a PHP script when an input field changes of value. The PHP script should delete the cached item from this specific input field.
The cache stores the old data of the input fields and the array has all of these input fields with the names of the fields and the values.
Now I can retrieve the full array but I want to retrieve a specific key from this array and delete it. I'm not sure how to retrieve a specific key out of this array.

This is the function that now only retrieves the full array:

```
public function emptySingleCache(){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $cache = Cache ::get('invoer');
}
```

I can retrieve the name of the input field with the $_GET[] request

The cache consists only of the names and values of the input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you keep the data in the cache. If you store an array, you can retrieve it as you already do, then use `unset` to forget the specific item from the array and store it once again.

if you want to remove the item from the cache with your key `invoer` then you can use

```
Cache::forget('invoer');
```

More details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/cache#removing-items-from-the-cache)

Comment: I fixed the problem, I pulled the cache and then I did a foreach through the full cache and changed the value of the specific name. Then I put the cache back. I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it but it works.

Comment: That's sounds like a bad operation performance wise. If you store an array of values, then you can get the array from the cache, and modify the item of the array directly given it's key. So you don't need to do foreach.

Comment: Here is the doc link. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache#removing-items-from-the-cache .Also make sure you don't **Store Items Forever in cache**.

Comment: @MartinterWee Please consider accepting the answer if it helped.